# How to properly convolve non-power-of-two image in a framebuffer with opengl

Tags: opengl, glsl, blur, convolution, framebuffer

I have a 800x600 window and I want to apply some convolution (i.e gaussian blur) to the rendered image.

First, I render the scene to a 1024x1024 float16 texture with a 800x600 viewport and scissor box. Thus, the area outside the viewport contains garbage, which looks like random colors on my machine. When I render this texture to the window with a fragment shader like this:

```glsl
uniform sampler2D tex;
out vec4 outFragColor;
smooth in vec2 texCoord;
const float weight[5] = float[] (0.227027, 0.1945946, 0.1216216, 0.054054, 0.016216);

void main()
{
    vec3 color = texture(tex, texCoord).rgb * weight[0];
    vec2 texOffset = 1.0f / textureSize(tex, 0);
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
        color += texture(tex, texCoord + vec2(texOffset.x * i, 0.0f)).rgb * weight[i];
        color += texture(tex, texCoord - vec2(texOffset.x * i, 0.0f)).rgb * weight[i];
    }
    outFragColor = vec4(color, 1.0f);
}
```

I obviously sample outside a viewport new window borders and get garbage mixed into the final image. For example, here we see random values on the top and zero values on the right:

[image]

What solutions I considered:

1) Render with a texture sized viewport and show a subimage only. A bad idea because fragment shader will do lots of useless work.

2) Use a slightly bigger viewport, i.e. 810x610. Looks like a mad hack.

3) Use non-power-of-two texture extensions. As far as I know, they have a subtle performance penalty, and, what's worse, they lack proper driver support and may be vendor-specific. Especially regarding float16 textures (which are crucial for the project), and WebGL.

So what is the best approach to convolve a framebuffered image with a kernel without sampling outside a viewport?

Comment: Have you looked at `glTexParameter` options for `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S`, `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T`? Why render to a texture that's larger than what you need, and leaves memory uninitialized? It makes no sense.

Comment: @BrettHale These options only make sense near texture borders, i.e. left and bottom in my case. Top and right edges are left unaffected as they are viewport borders only. I render to a larger texture to keep it's dimensions to be powers of two for compatibility with various chips and drivers.

Comment: "*Use non-power-of-two texture extensions.*" NPOTs have been core behavior in OpenGL for ***over a decade***. You should feel absolutely no hesitation in using them. Not unless you need your code to work on truly ancient hardware. And since you need 16-bit floats (which is provided by hardware that's NPOT-capable), that's clearly not the case.